# Looping over fifty elements at a time (matlab)

Tags: matlab

I am currently new to matlab, and I am trying to do a loop over fifty elements at a time instead of one element at a time. For example, I have a list of 1000 elements, and I would like to compute the sum for every fifty elements. Instead of doing a sum function through indexing, it would be much faster with a loop. How would I go about doing this?

I.e. [1,...50th element, 51th element... 100...]
Output would be the the sum values of 1:50, 51:100, 101:150... and so on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `nums=1:1000;for ii=1:50:nums(end);disp(sum(nums(ii:ii+50));end` but I guaratee that you'll need to tweakthat some before it works. It should get you started though!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure what you mean by "a sum function through indexing", but there are various ways to do this.  In general I try to avoid explicit loops in Matlab and let MathWorks functions do their magic.

```
results = zeros(20,1); 
for i = 1:20
    results(i) = sum(1 + (50 * (i - 1)):50 + 50 * (i - 1));
end
```

Another option is to do something like `arrayfun`.

```
sIndex = 1:50:951;
eIndex = 50:50:1000;
result = arrayfun(@(x, y) sum(x:y), sIndex, eIndex);
```

You could also use reshape and sum to do it one shot.

```
numbers = 1:1000;
numbers2 = reshape(numbers, 50, []);
result = sum(numbers2);
```

This last method is what I personally would say is a Matlab way of doing it.  `arrayfun` is basically a wrapper around a loop and the loop is...well a loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I run into another similar issue. I am trying to fit a best-fit line across a data set using polyfit(x, y, 1). X is a list of numbers, while y is another list of numbers. I am trying to fit a line through the first fifty numbers in each x and y, and continue to do so till the end of the list. Essentially, I am taking a best fit line through every 50 elements in the list. Like the issue I have before, I am trying to do this without explicitly typing a new polyfit() for every 50 elements.

Comment: @Tom, in this case you would need a loop since `polyfit` does not accept more than one vector of input for `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need the sum, you can also use [`movsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movsum.html):

```
array = 1:1000;
win = 50; % window size
msum = movsum(array,win,'Endpoints','discard');
```

in the same way, you can use:

`movmax`    Moving maximum
`movmean`   Moving mean
`movmedian` Moving median
`movmin`    Moving minimum
`movstd`    Moving standard deviation
`movvar`    Moving variance

Answer (score 1):

Using `cumsum` and `diff` you can obtain the desired result.

```
C = [0 cumsum(a)];
out = diff(C(1:50:end));
```